# Why no output of this code? Where is the error?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

This is a code on my php website where this page comes out blank except header menu which shows logged in user. I just can't find the error. 
Since favitems table is empty, it should display you do not have any product message.

```
<?php
include("includes/config.php");
include 'includes/header.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){

    header("Location:login.php");

}else{

    $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM favitems 
        WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
        or die("ERROR :<hr>".mysql_error());

    if($test == NULL){

        echo "<div class=products>";
        echo "<br>You have no products to show!";
        echo "</div>";

    } else {

        While ($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)){

            echo "<div class='products'>";

            $id        = $row['itemid'];
            $query     = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products 
                                   WHERE id =".$id);
            $q         = mysql_fetch_array($query);

            echo $q['item_name']." "; echo $q['brand_name']."<br>";
            echo $q['qty']."<br>";
            echo $q['category']."<br>"; 
            echo $q['state']."<br>";
            echo "<br><a href=view.php?id=".$q['item_id'].">
            View item</a>";

        }   
        echo "</div>";


    }
}
include("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will return FALSE on faliure and not NULL

Comment: Can we see the HTML output?

Comment: What are the current error settings?  First thing you should try to do is look at the error log in order to isolate where the problem is.

Comment: This won't answer the question but it's a security issue. Change this `header("Location:login.php");` to this `header("Location:login.php"); exit();`. If you don't, the rest of the code will still be executed.

Comment: Check scope of variable $row.  ($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)){{

Comment: It should be if() {}  else if( ) {} else { }

Comment: Just as an aside, have a look into using `mysqli` instead of the deprecated `mysql`. Also your code queries are vulnerable to SQL injection, so either pass your variables through `mysql_real_escape_string` (preferably `mysqli_real_escape_string`) or use prepared statements.

Comment: What about `var_dump($test)`

Comment: @caCtus The out put just shows header and footer content.

Comment: @user2784840 OK thats a good idea.

Comment: @Heru-Luin but user is logged in and has a live session.

Comment: @Mangesh you mean to say I should change else { to elseif

Comment: @user2039716 Not even a closing `</div>` that is not included in header and footer content? (The one you have after your `while` loop.) You should learn how to debug your code. Start by adding some simple `echo` at every step in order to see where it doesn't work as expected. Playing with error settings as user2784840 said  is a good idea. You will save time!

Comment: @user2039716 try to avoid many if else's in your code. Page will perform faster. If you are redirecting when session is unset then no need of else here.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      header("Location:login.php");
      exit;
}

 1. Execute your query here 
 2. If error found throw Error message 
 3. If successful execution, Check no of rows fetched


  if(row_fetched > 0 )  {
        // print table
  } else {
    // print no recors found
  }


 include("includes/footer.php");
```

Also Check you variable scope  and return values of all inbuilt function you are using here.